# Destroy a class instance on creating the new instance

Tags: class, delphi, instance, delphi-xe2, destroy

I am programming an MDIChild form in Delphi with the Action = caFree in OnClose event. Now I want that at one time there will only be one instance of a form. For this I used a class variable:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
...
class var CurInstance: TMyForm;
...
end;

constructor TMyForm.Create();
begin
inherited Create(nil);
if Assigned(TMyForm.CurInstance) then
  TMyForm.CurInstance.Destroy

TMyForm.CurInstance := Self;
end;

destructor TMyForm.Destroy();
begin
TMyForm.CurInstance := nil;
inherited Destroy;
end;
```

The code above works pretty well and does what it should be. But I have a bad feeling about calling destructor from constructor, even through this is a different instance. Is this a correct way? Is there something else I need to consider about this?

Many thanks.

Comment: `if Assigned(TMyForm.CurInstance) then TMyForm.CurInstance.Destroy` is the same thing as `TMyForm.CurInstance.Free`. The whole point of `TObject.Free` is to do `if Assigned then Destroy` (basically).

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. Still, it doesn't resolve the problem. Even if I do Free, I still call destructor from the constructor

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you are doing, provided that you don't inherit from a class that that also assigns itself to CurInstance (which you don't).

Comment: It's just my colleague says that it's dangerous to call Destroy from Create. I don't inherit from the class that assigns itself to CurInstance, so I also can't understand why this is dangerous in my particular case

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally wrong with this code, calling a destructor of instance A from the constructor of instance B is valid. However, this surely isn't the right way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, David. Would you be so kind to tell me, where I am mistaken?

Comment: I'm not really sure what problem you are trying to solve. Something along the lines of White's answer is usually what I'd expect to see here.